# Calling Method on TabChange

Tags: android, android-activity, call

I tried to refresh a Layout, on a Tab-Change but I failed:

Main Activity

```java
package com.hello;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;


public class HelloAndroidActivity extends TabActivity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WatchActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("watch").setIndicator("Watch",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.watch))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Settings",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.settings))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ResultsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("results").setIndicator("Results",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.results))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            WatchActivity s = new WatchActivity();
            s.setBoatsinWatch();

            }


    });


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

Watch Activity:

```
  public class WatchActivity extends Activity {      
    List<String> boat_names = new ArrayList<String>();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.watch);     
 }
    public void setBoatsinWatch() {

        //setContentView(R.layout.watch);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.boats);
        ll.removeAllViews();

        int j;
        SettingsActivity s = new SettingsActivity();


        s.initBoatNames();
        boat_names = s.getBoats();

        for (j=1;j<boat_names.size();j++) {

            LinearLayout bl = new LinearLayout(this);
            bl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            bl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

           Button b = new Button(this);
           b.setText(boat_names.get(j));
           b.setWidth(200);
           b.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
           tv.setTextSize(20);
           tv.setText("0");
           tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           tv.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);

           ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
           ib.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.finish);

           bl.addView(b);
           bl.addView(tv);
           bl.addView(ib);
           ll.addView(bl);
        }

    }
```

Watch.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:weightSum="2">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text=""         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="30dp"></TextView>  
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/boats"     android:orientation="vertical">    
     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You should be starting WatchActivity instead of instantiating it

```
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        startActivity(new Intent(HelloAndroidActivity.this, WatchActivity.class)
        }


});
```

Then you should call your `setBoatsInWatch()` from your `WatchActivity.onCreate()`.

As per comments, below, this answer solves the immediate problem.

Comment: Not gone, just sent back on the stack behind the new Activity window. The important thing is to understand that you need to start Activities rather than instantiate them. Now you should rethink your UI options; perhaps a new activity isn't what you need. (Can't help you there, yet, because I'm not sure what effect you're trying to accomplish.) Also, the Android version that you're targeting could be relevant (as per the fragment "trick" discussed in the TabActivity javadoc).

Comment: the trick should be to reload or restart the Tab WatchActivity in the current UI. The user has the opportunity to set up the watch and with this settings the watch needs to be designed. So what would be the best way to get to a solution where I see the tab UI?

Comment: Let's start by getting a better picture of what you want. Near as I can tell, you are trying to define a screen with a few tabs, one of which is Watch. The other tabs let the user do things that should affect the contents of Watch, and you are using onTabChanged as an opportunity to tell WatchActivity to update itself. Close?

Comment: First, accept the answer if that solved the original problem. Second, here's where I make a suggestion and then bow out because I haven't done it myself, yet. Instead of using separate Activities for each tab (which is my experience), I suggest defining one TabActivity to contain everything. I have seen posts that describe putting all components in one view and simply changing which are visible based on current tab. Since all the UI code is in the same Activity (and same lifecycle), you can simply update whatever components you want regardless of current tab.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier solution!

Just add the for each tab:

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Cool; I had not considered the possibility that Android mirrored the Activity-window-stack behavior in Tabs. +1 Unfortunately, CommonsWare (one of the core developers) [recommends against the navigation paradigm that you are attempting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890617/android-stack-management-for-views-in-a-tab/2891683#2891683). If you stick with it, though, you'll probably need the answer to [BackButton dont call last activity in history stack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6444684/424529) as well.

Comment: Your original TabChange question morphed into a new navigation topic. If I may be so bold, I think that you should close the original question by accepting my answer. The questions that I mentioned in my previous comment cover your new navigation topic, but if you think there is more to add, then ask a new question and answer it yourself -- that would turn your knowledge into a concise unit that others can query.

Answer (score 0):

Your WatchActivity has no layout yet, hence the null pointer exception for findViewById.

You need to call setContentView before you call findViewById. I see you have it commented out there, unless it is called somewhere else that hasn't been posted here?

Comment: I geht this error then: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 WatchActivity(Activity).setContentView(int) line: 1647

Comment: I presume you have a layout in res/layout called watch.xml? If so check the headers in your WatchActivity and make sure you aren't importing android.R. If you are change it to yournamespace.R e.g. com.myproject.R;

Comment: Yes I have a watch.xml and in the header I am not importing android.R. my imports are: package com.hello;

import java.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

Comment: Could you edit the original post and put up the entire activity please and also add the contents of watch.xml